# array.includes returns false using regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have this array:

`array = ['S2B_MSIL1C_20180310T041559_N0206_R090_T46QEK_20180310T075716.SAFE'];`

and this regex:

`regex = new RegExp('S2B_MSIL1C_20180310T041559_N0206_R090_T46QEK_20180310T075716' + '.SAFE','g');`

When I use `array.includes(regex);` , `false` is returned. Have I missed something?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Array.includes() will not perform regex match

Comment: `array` contains one [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String), you expect it to contain a [`Regexp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Comment: As @RaR commented, `array.includes` does not use regex, see more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use `Array.some`

```
var yourRegex = /pattern/g ;
var atLeastOneMatches = array.some(e => yourRegex.test(e));
```

Array.some returns true after the *first one in the array* returns true. If it goes through the whole array with no `true`, it returns false.

Comment: or even `array.some(yourRegex.test);`

Answer (score 2):

RgExps are not for searching on Arrays, and includes method is for finding if your required object is included on the array or not. and here you passed and Regex object to your include method so it tells you that there is no regex object included your array.

you have to do one of the belows:

```
array.includes('S2B_MSIL1C_20180310T041559_N0206_R090_T46QEK_20180310T075716' + '.SAFE');
```

or

```
var yourRegex = /pattern/g ;
for(var i = 0 ; i<arr.length ; i++)
{
    if(yourRegex.test(arr[i]))
    {
        //Founded
        return true;
    }
}
```